# Prononciation du prénom Anne

Tags: prononciation, oral, québec

Aujourd’hui au Québec, on prononce [an] le prénom Anne, comme probablement dans la majorité de la Francophonie. Cependant, quand on parle de Sainte-Anne (la personne ou un lieu nommé d’après elle), il est habituel d’entendre [sẽtɑːn] (sintâne) voire   [sẽtɑ̃ːn] (sinte-an-nn).

Y a-t-il une raison historique à ce fait de l’usage oral contemporain ? Ou est-ce la combinaison avec *Sainte* qui provoque le changement de la valeur de la voyelle ? Si c’est le cas, pourrait-on en fournir d’autres exemples à l’appui ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Je ne suis pas l'auteur de la réponse, mais ce serait lié à une ancienne prononciation de Anne, qui serait Ânne.

> Il s'agit d'une vieille prononciation française que le Québec a
>   conservée, comme beaucoup d'autres traits du français des XVIIe et
>   XVIIIe siècles. Ce «a postérieur», comme l'appellent les linguistes
>   parce qu'il est prononcé plus à l'arrière de la bouche que le «a
>   antérieur» (celui de patte, par exemple), n'existait pas en latin et
>   n'est apparu que lorsque nos ancêtres médiévaux cessèrent de prononcer
>   certaines consonnes placées à la fin des syllabes, explique Claude
>   Poirier, professeur de linguistique à l'Université Laval. Cela eut
>   pour effet d'allonger la voyelle précédant la consonne abandonnée, ce
>   qui, pour certains mots du moins, a débouché sur notre fameux «â»
>   national.
>
> Ainsi, le mot âne provient de l'ancien français asne, dont on
>   prononçait le «s» et dont le «a» était à l'origine antérieur. Le même
>   phénomène a transformé d'autres mots, comme bastard qui se changea en
>   bâtard, haste en hâte, etc. C'est vraisemblablement par une sorte de
>   «contagion» à partir du mot âne que le prénom Anne, qui vient de
>   l'hébraïque Hannah, a vu sa prononciation muter, dit M. Poirier.
>
> À leur grand dam, à peu près toutes les Anne, Marianne et Anne-Marie
>   du Québec en ont un jour fait les frais, mais cette prononciation
>   était autrefois la norme, et personne ne s'en formalisait. Pour tout
>   dire, même dans les régions françaises de l'Aunis et de la Saintonge
>   au début du XXe siècle, le mot année se prononçait encore ânnée.
>
> Donc, avant, on disait Ânne.  On a donc juste continuer de dire Ânne
>   avec Ste-Ânne même si on s'est mit à dire Anne avec un a aigu.

[Lien ici](http://forumdupeuple.com/?topic=162.0)

Le texte fait référence à un article, dont voici un [extrait](https://web.archive.org/web/20100129043747/http://www.cyberpresse.ca/le-soleil/vivre-ici/la-science-au-quotidien/200910/17/01-912390-detour-linguistique.php) qui donne des exemples de l'usage;

> À leur grand dam, à peu près toutes les Anne, Marianne et Anne-Marie
>   du Québec en ont un jour fait les frais, mais cette prononciation
>   était autrefois la norme, et personne ne s'en formalisait. Pour tout
>   dire, même dans les régions françaises de l'Aunis et de la Saintonge
>   au début du XXe siècle, le mot année se prononçait encore ânnée.
>
> Et qui ne se souvient pas du refrain de la vieille chanson Marianne
>   s'en va-t-au moulin, dont les vers ne riment vraiment que si l'on
>   prononce le prénom de l'héroïne avec un «a» postérieur :
>
> Le loup a mangé l'âne
>
> Ma p'tite mam'zelle Marianne
>
> Le loup a mangé l'âne Catin
>
> Par-derrière le moulin.

Comment: La chanson qui ne rime qu’avec le maintien d’une prononciation ancienne me rappelle cette autre chanson, dont deux vers ne riment pas du tout au Québec: «Écoutez les **clochettes**  //  Du joyeux temps des **Fêtes**». Par ailleurs, c'est vrai que Mariânne était plus répandu chez les plus vieux du temps de ma jeunesse, au point de n’être pas surprenant lorsqu’on l’entendait.

Comment: @Montéedelait Bonne example pour cette autre chanson :) je n'y avait pas pensée et tu a raison.