# Prononciation du mot "mœurs"

Tags: prononciation

L'autre jour j'ai utilisé le mot mœurs en prononçant \mœʁ\. Je n'ai pas été compris et j'ai dû épeler le mot. On m'a dit que la prononciation correcte est \mœʁs\.
Le lemme du mot dans [wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/bonnes_m%C5%93urs) confirme cette affirmation :

> Il est devenu courant de prononcer le s à la fin du mot « mœurs » : \mœʁs\.

Y a-t-il une explication pour cette évolution ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Le *S* final de certains mots a pu se faire entendre, disparaître puis réapparaître au fil des siècles.

Il ne faut pas forcément chercher une explication rationnelle. Quand un mot est peu fréquent à l'oral, sa graphie peut parfois influencer la prononciation (ex.: *[gageure](https://dictionnaire.orthodidacte.com/article/prononciation-gageure)*). On prononce d'abord les mots comme on a l'habitude de les entendre donc si quelqu'un se met à prononcer un mot d'une façon particulière, sa prononciation peut faire tache d'huile et se répandre largement.

*Pancréas*, *mœurs*, *détritus*, *rébus*, *anis*, *moins* ont des [prononciations variables suivant les individus et les régions](https://francaisdenosregions.com/2018/12/11/taisez-ce-s-que-je-ne-saurais-entendre/).

On peut aussi noter les différences et quelquefois les incertitudes  dans la prononciation de toponymes comme Paris, Reims, Amiens, Cassis, Gers, Anvers...

Des mots comme *[ours](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ours)* voire même *Mars* ont été prononcés /ur/ et /maʁ/ dans le passé alors que le *S* est toujours prononcé aujourd'hui.

La difficulté à se faire comprendre sur un mot peut aussi tenir au contexte d'utilisation dudit mot. *Mœurs* est souvent employé dans des expressions figées ou quasiment figées (*Police des mœurs, brigade des mœurs, une affaire de mœurs, des mœurs dissolues, les bonnes mœurs, les mœurs et coutumes*, *autre temps, autre mœurs*, etc.) donc si ta phrase ne suivait pas un modèle courant, ça a pu avoir une influence sur ce qui t'est arrivé.

Comment: *Marc* est un autre exemple de lettre finale prononcée ou pas selon l'individu. (... et vivement l'introduction du G cédille pour *gag¸ure* :~) )

Comment: @Pasunclue Oui. Même quand on prononce le *C* de Marc, on omet généralement de le faire dans *Place Saint-Marc*.

Comment: Je pensais à celui de café, qui permettrait selon certains d'entrevoir l'avenir :) Pour le prénom, tu m'apprends à l'instant qu'il n'est pas toujours prononcé...

Comment: @Pasunclue Saint-Marc (la place ou la lessive) permettent peut-être de lire l'avenir ;-)

Comment: @Pasunclue Quand il n'est pas précédé de Saint, je pense que le *C* du prénom Marc est toujours prononcé aujourd'hui.

Comment: C'est noté, merci. Pour le saint, un village près de chez-moi s'appelle Saint-Marc et tous en prononcent le C. Il semble donc que ce soit un autre exemple de flottement dans l'usage... Pour [Sainte-Anne](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/38436/13100) par contre, nous avons ici aussi un contraste avec le prénom.

Answer (score 2):

Voici ce qui est lisible dans le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/moeurs) à la partie « prononciation » du mot « mœurs ».

> [moe(:)ʀ(s)]. Martinet-Walter 1973 [moe:ʀ]; [moeʀs] (7/11). Les dict. ont, de Fér. 1768 à Besch. 1845, [moeʀs]; dep. Littré, les deux formes, avec des modalités diverses. Littré préconise l'anc. prononc., [moe:ʀ]: ,,[moeʀs] n'est pas une bonne prononciation`. Nyrop Phonét. 1951, §254, 7: [moe:ʀ] est ,,recherché`. DG, Barbeau-Rodhe 1930, Lar. Lang. fr.: [moe:ʀ] est ,,vieilli`. Pt Rob. ,,[moe:ʀ], souv. [moeʀs], fam.` Lexis 1975 ,,[moeʀs] ou, plus souvent, [moe:ʀ]``. Fouché Prononc. 1959, p.478, Dupré 1972, pris ensemble, suggèrent la répartition suiv.: un homme de moeurs lâches [moe:ʀ]; moeurs irréprochables [moeʀz] ou [moeʀs]; affaire de moeurs [moeʀs]. Att. ds Ac. dep. 1694.

Cela explique la difficulté de compréhension; on se heurte à un usage diversifié, difficile à suivre, que l'on peut même qualifier de mal établi. Je suis cependant entièrement d'accord avec [l'OQLF](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=2401).

> Les prononciations [mœʀ] (meur), comme dans heure, et [mœʀs] (meurs), en prononçant le s final, sont attestées depuis quelques siècles. On a longtemps privilégié la prononciation [mœʀ] (meur) mais aujourd’hui la prononciation [mœʀs] (meurs) est plus fréquente.

Une explication serait que dans une conversation, « [mœʀ] » semble plus difficile à identifier à l'oreille que « [mœʀs] » ; cela et l'incertitude qui règne sur l'acception particulière que l'on attache aux deux prononciations a conduit vers une simplification dans le  sens  de s'en tenir à une forme qui cause le moins de problèmes. La référence qui se trouve ci-dessous contribue à une justification de ce point de vue.

> ([projet Voltaire](https://www.projet-voltaire.fr/culture-generale/vingt-mots-vocabulaire-francais-prononciation-difficile-1/))
> MŒURS
> La tentation : faire entendre le « s » final et prononcer [meurss].
> La bonne prononciation : l’usage traditionnel (pour ne pas dire vieilli) rend le « s » muet, mais dans le langage courant, il se prononce, et permet d’éviter la confusion avec le verbe mourir (meurt). Vous avez donc le choix.